# base64 encoded md5 hash in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a way to do a base64 encoded md5 hash in terraform? As far as I can tell, terraform only does md5 and base64 encodings of the raw strings.

The use case is that I have a google cloud storage object that I'm creating in terraform, but it says the "detectmd5hash" property has changed every time even though it hasn't.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "things" {
  name    = "my-things"
  bucket  = "my-google-cloud-storage-bucket"
  content = "${local.thing_two}\n${local.thing_one}"
}
```

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "things" {
  name    = "my-things"
  bucket  = "my-google-cloud-storage-bucket"
  detectmd5hash = base64encode(md5("${local.thing_two}\n${local.thing_one}"))
  content = "${local.thing_two}\n${local.thing_one}"
}
```

But that is taking the base64 encoding of the actual hex string, not the bytes that the hex represents -- so it doesn't match the actual md5 of the object that google stores (it returns md5 in hex).

Are there any workarounds or clever solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem with `AWS S3`, which we worked around by:

- setting up a gulp pipeline that calculates the file's hash
- stores that hash in a .txt file(using the same name as the original file)
- Upload both file and hash .txt file
- Then use `base64encode` on the .txt file for versioning

That worked for awhile, but in the end we chose to use the S3 built-in object versioning, since it was much easier.

I haven't used `terraform` for Google, so I'm not sure if this is helpful, but feel free to ask me more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party here, but I think you're looking for [`filemd5`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/filemd5) .